# Django CORS - localhost with any port

Tags: python, django, api, request, cors

I'm running into a CORS issue with my Django app. I've got it configured properly and I've narrowed the issue down to my list of URLs - settings `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` fixes it.

This is my current list:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    ...
]
```

My front end is a Flutter app, the problem is that in development Flutter runs on any random port e.g., `localhost:12345`, so I can't hard code this into the CORS list.

How can I add `localhost` with any arbitrary port to the list? I can't seem to find docs on it, the only alternative seems to be to just allow everything which  I'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually realized how to solve this right after posting.

The [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) package supports regex matching as well. I ended up using the following:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    # match localhost with any port
    r"^http:\/\/localhost:*([0-9]+)?$",
    r"^https:\/\/localhost:*([0-9]+)?$",
]
```

This will match `https://localhost:<PORT>` and `http://localhost:<PORT>`.